Craft CMS v4 -> v5 upgrade *** failed to apply m230511_215903_content_refactor
I'm trying to upgrade a local Craft CMS site from the latest version of 4 to the most recent version of 5. I've followed the official upgrade guide but i'm having an issue when the migrations are running.
When I run composer update, I get the following error.
*** failed to apply m230511_215903_content_refactor. 

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Are you sure this problem is directly related to Composer? Usually, migrations are not executed by Composer

Recently ran into this myself. Check your db for the existence of a table called lenz_linkfield and delete it. Afterward you can run php craft up and your migrations should run successfully.
Obviously, make a full backup of your DB, and test this in a local environment first!
This error relates to the now abandonded typed linkfield plugin. Back story an additional info here: https://github.com/sebastian-lenz/craft-linkfield/issues/261
